# Need a data structure that allows duplicate key

Tags: c#

I have data in rows that looks like this:

(car, color, age)

For example:

Ford,red,4

Toyota,green,3

Ford,blue,2

I need to loop over these data rows and perform validation before submitting to a stored procedure. In this case, if there is more than one car of the same type I need to ensure the colors are different. So the example above would be permitted, but this example would not:

Ford,red,4

Toyota,green,3

Ford,red,2

How do I do that in C#. I have tried using a Dictionary, but it does not allow duplicate keys. A list does not seem the correct option either? Can any offer any direction? Thanks.

Comment: Servy has pointed you in the right direction (composite keys). If you actually had duplicate keys a dictionary would also work, you would simply create a Dictionary<yourKeyType, List<yourDataType>>.

Answer (score 10):

You don't actually have duplicate keys, you simply have a key that is made up of two values (a composite key), specifically your values are a car and a color.  So you need an object that represents a car/color pair, and that has equality implemented based on those two values.

This means that you don't need a different data structure, `Dictionary` is fine, you just need to come up with an appropriate type to use as the key for that dictionary.  Neither a car nor a color alone as a key accomplishes what you want.

You could write your own; just a class with two properties and appropriate `Equals/GetHashCode` overrides, and if this is something you use in multiple places in your application or from a sufficiently large scope, you should do just that.  If you're only using this in a limited and localized scope, you can just use `Tuple<Car, Color>` as your dictionary key.

Comment: The .NET version i have to use does not support Tuple. (However, I am using this in a limited/localized scope.) How would I create the class you suggest with 2 properties and appropriate Equals/GetHashCode overrides?

Comment: @user3666516 Then I guess you'll need to create a new type to hold a car/color pair.

Answer (score 0):

If [Servy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30245796/80274) does not apply to you and you really are just keyed on car (for example you may have multiple cars of the same color).

There is a type built in that behaves similar to a `ReadOnlyDictionary<Tkey, IEnumerable<TValue>>` where the enumerable holds the collisions, it is a [`ILookup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534291(v=vs.100).aspx).

The easiest way to construct one is using the [`.ToLookup(`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method in LINQ.

```
class Row
{
    public CarEnum Car {get; set;}
    public string Color {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;
}


void Validate(List<Row> rows)
{
   //I did not use "var" to make it more obvious what is going on, in production code I would use "var".
   ILookup<CarEnum, Row> rowLookup = rows.ToLookup((row)=>row.Car);

   foreach(IGrouping<CarEnum, Row> carKey in rowLookup)
   {
       //This loop would loop once for Ford, once for Toyota

       foreach(Row row in carKey)
       {
           //This loop would loop twice in the Ford iteration and lope once in the Toyota iteration. 
           DoValidate(row);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another solution would be to find duplicates using a GroupBy expression:

```
public void Validate(List<Row> rows)
{
    var sameCarColorMoreThanOne = rows.GroupBy(ks => new { ks.Car, ks.Color })
                                      .Select(s => new { s.Key, Count = s.Count() })
                                      .Where(p => p.Count > 1);
    if (sameCarColorMoreThanOne.Any())
        throw new ExceptionWithListOfDuplicateKeys(sameCarColorMoreThanOne.Select(s => new Tuple<string, string>(s.Key.Car, s.Key.Color)).ToList());
}
```

Where ExceptionWithListOfDuplicateKeys is just some thought up Exception type which holds a list of tuples of offending car/color combinations

Comment: Re-constructing the entire lookup every time you want to look up a particular value is generally not a very good idea.  Better to just construct the lookup once and query it multiple times.  You're using an anonymous type as the key here, which will work fine, but only if the query (or lookup constructed from it) never leaves the scope of the method it's defined in, which doesn't sound like the situation the OP is in.  If he was creating, using, and then discarding the lookup *within the scope of one method* using an anonymous type as a key could be viable.

Comment: Added .ToList() in the Exception constructor. Now the only thing which will ever escape the scope of the Validate method is a list of tuples of strings - and the tuple list will only be constructed once. Replacing the tuples with a type as you point out in your comment above is straightforward

Comment: The question is asking for a `Dictionary` (or an analogous data structure) that can do the lookup.  You aren't providing a way of constructing such an object, rather you're re-constructing the lookup every single time in this method (in your LINQ query).

Comment: The OP is not specifically asking for a Dictionary - he says that he is trying to perform validation and is using a Dictionary and then looping over that to do the validation. Instead my method is selecting all the entries that have several instances of same car/color directly - if there are none sameCarColorMoreThanOne will be empty and your validation is done - if there are any I'm throwing some exception holding a list of the entries that are in violation on the uniqueness